# Detect motion with moving camera

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, opticalflow

How can I track objects movement when the camera is moving. Example if the camera is inside a vehicle. So far I have tied the algorithms in Optical Flow in Emgu Cv. I want to get the horizontal movement of object. But they don't give enough results to detect a movement horizontally when camera is moving forward.

pyrLK is good point tracker but when i take the difference between new calculated point and previous points it doesn't make a sense, maybe for each frame there will be new points added. Is it possible with single camera or do i have to use stereo vision. Please someone suggest any help with this. I'll be really appreciated.

thanks

(hope the question is not too broad)

Comment: To detect movement you need something static. Wrong way. Right way is to *detect object*. If they are of known shape, then detecting them will solve your issue as well. You have to describe more application, because generic solution is not exist yet.. well, making AI being able to learn and then recognize things is an option =D

Comment: To track movement of an object from a moving platform you need object recognition, which is not a simple task even in software.  Particularly if the object is not of known color or shape, like something moving in front of your car.  This task usually requires hardware specifically designed for the task (see: FPGAs) since your whole reference frame is in motion, it is difficult to perform these full-frame translations and computations in real-time using just software libraries.  Sinatr is generally correct in that you cannot use simple motion detection algorithms.

Comment: If you mean SLAM, then take a look at: https://openslam.org/ and  http://www.mrpt.org/ .

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg6Nz6BfoSQ what about this video. it is in c++. But I'm familiar with c# . Will i able to implement this with Emgu Cv

Comment: afaik with a real dense optical flow you can guess the camera movement (in/out of the scene for example, the flow has a special pattern). So if you have extracted that main flow pattern, everything that flows in directions not according to the pattern is noise or a moving object. But thats just theory, no idea whether this works in pratice ;)

Comment: here are two example flow pattern: person looking backward out of a moving train: http://www.simplypsychology.org/optic-flow.jpg and a pilot flying towards a landing glide: http://www.simplypsychology.org/gibson.jpg all taken from: http://www.simplypsychology.org/perception-theories.html

Comment: @Sinatr can you have a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg6Nz6BfoSQ please

Comment: Well, that video shows you can detect motion, nothing else (you get illusion what cars are detected, but they are just seen differently than empty road). Notice, pedestrians become visible when car is stopped. Detecting objects over moving something is not what 1 camera can do. What I could think of is to have 2 cameras, which collect *same* data (moving same path), but with delay. If something is changed between 2 snapshots of same picture of same static place - it can be detected somehow.

Comment: @Sinatr I think it detects, did you watched after 4.15min it detects the horizontal movement even when the car moving forward (but in lower speed).

Comment: @Sinatr hi can you kindly check this paper out.
http://users.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/~steve/asset/index.html
In that paper he detected corners first and tracked them using a motion model. im stuck at there. If you know can you explain how to use a motion model to track feature points. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of color tracking. If the objects you attempt to track have a distinct color, you should be able to target them adequately.

One way to accomplish this is to choose an appropriate space for color as RGB space. Keep in mind this may be too sensitive, even to small illumination variance. (It really depends on the objects you want to track and tracking scenario.)